# getInputStream in Async Task

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, socketserver

I have an Activity which calls an Async task to accept socket connections through a predefined InetAddress.

The Async task calls another Async task to listen for messages in. but it hangs on the get input stream

I have been racking my brain for hours and cannot work out why it is hanging...any help please.

```
public void startSocketListener(InetAddress groupOwnerAddress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AcceptClientThread accept;
    try {
        accept = new AcceptClientThread();
        accept.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public class AcceptClientThread extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>{

    public AcceptClientThread() throws IOException{

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("CONNECTION ERR", "Could not close serverSocket " + e.toString());
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("CONNECTION ERR","Could not listen on port: " + port);
            onCancelled();
        }

        while (listening){
            try {
                Log.i("CONNECTION", "AWAITING CONNECTION TO CLIENT");
                Socket newSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.i("CONNECTION", "CONNECTED TO CLIENT");
                ListenerThread lThread = new ListenerThread(newSocket);
                lThread.execute("Do it");
                Log.i("CONNECTION", "ACCEPTED CLIENT");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                onProgressUpdate("could not accept client");
            }

        }
        Log.i("CONNECTION", "close socket");
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "table connected";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // received data is first element in the String
        //Toast.makeText(KitchenActivity.this, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public class ListenerThread extends AsyncTask<String, Order, Void> {

    private Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    public ListenerThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream()); //hangs here
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `listening` ever `false`? Right now it looks like you have an `infinite loop` which keeps trying to create a new `Socket` unless I am missing something.

Comment: listening does equal false when the user closes the activity or presses a button. This just listens for incoming connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

> **Threading rules**
>
> There are a few threading rules that must be followed
> for this class to work properly:
>
> The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done
> automatically as of JELLY_BEAN. The task instance must be created on
> the UI thread.

You can handle this by calling your new `Thread` in the `onPostExecute()` of your first `AsyncTask` after your `accept()` is successful, as `onPostExecute()` runs on the `UI`

Also, without looking at it more, I believe that you would want to break out of your `while loop` in the first task after it accepts the request. Then when you need to make another connection you create a new instance of this task in your `UI` and `execute` it again. I'm not positive about that last part without looking at it longer but that seems right

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess you only can call AsyncTask.execute() from UI-thread, and you are trying to do it from doInBackground(), which runs in separate thread.

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to have as many connections as possible, I'll put it into an array and try it

Comment: AsyncTask are designed for background work. Handling requests as a server does requires you to implement something more appropriate such as a pool of worker threads ready to handle these requests. You want to look at the ThreadPoolExecutor class.